# How to make a header item with subheader using objectlistview

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I'm working with C# and `ObjetListView`, I'm trying to do the attached image but it's not coming out.

Thank you for taking the time to read and help me beforehand

[image]

Comment: I am not aware that this kind of concept is directly supported. Do you REALLY need it to be display this way? Kind of a workaround could be to use a slightly different font or background color to indicate that those sub-items are related. It really depends on your actual use case.

Comment: Not really, but aesthetically it looks better that way.

But if it can not be done, nothing happens

Comment: You could do it with `OwnerDrawHeader` and  `DrawColumnHeader` event handler but it would be a ton of work (especially with column resizing etc) and probably not worth it.